# How do you attach a range slider's thumb to a corner of a div to adjust the size of that div based on the slider's value?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build this range slider where the thumb is attached to the bottom right corner of a rectangle (specifically, the center of the thumb is attached to the bottom right corner). So far I've tried styling the track with no luck especially because I want to have borders on the slider so I then attempted to do it by building it with CSS Grid and having column width change. [This example](https://codepen.io/jollyjwhiskers/pen/VwppYdb) is my latest attempt with Flexbox and changing the width of a background element.

The maximum range of the slider is 100, so I use that value to change the percentage of the background element. With all of these methods that I have tried, I always run into the same problem; depending on where the range slider is, the thumb and the corner do not align perfectly.

I'm sure there's something I've missed or a better way to accomplish what I want, so after hours of trying on my own, I figured it's time to get some help.

The code in the example is just a snippet of a more complex slider that can also be manipulated with a number input, so this issue is really noticeable when fine tuning the value.

```js
let range = document.getElementById("rangeSlider");
let rangeInput = Math.round(range.value);
let newVal;
function init(){
  newVal = 0;
}
function updateSlider(rangeInput) {
  newVal = range.value;
  let blue = document.querySelector(".range__input__right--bg");
  let blueWidth = newVal + "%";

  blue.style.width = blueWidth;
  console.log(rangeInput);
}


range.addEventListener("change", () => {
  updateSlider(newVal);
});
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        init();
    });
```

```css
@mixin track() {
  height: 0;
}
@mixin thumb() {
  appearance: none;
  height: 37px;
  width: 37px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.range {
  //RANGE
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    &__input {
      height: 115px;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      &__left,
      &__right {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      &__left {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 116.82px;
        background: #fff663;
        border-top: 2px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
        border-left: 2px solid #333;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-right: 2px solid #333;
      }
      &__right {
        //width: 92%;
        position: relative;
        &--bg {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          background: #c4f3e8;
          border-top: 2px solid #333;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
          border-right: 2px solid #333;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        }
      }
      input[type="range"] {
        position: absolute;
        appearance: none;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 105%;
        &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          @include thumb;
        }
        &::-moz-range-thumb {
          @include thumb;
        }
        &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
          @include track;
        }

        &::-moz-range-track {
          @include track;
        }

        &::-ms-track {
          @include track;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='rangeContainer' class="range">
  <div class="range__input">
      <div class="range__input__left">Must Stay Solid</div>
      <div class="range__input__right">
        <div class="range__input__right--bg">Must resize with Range Slider</div>
        <input id="rangeSlider" type="range" value="100" max="100">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the `updateSlider` function you set `newVal = range.value;` but later use `let blueWidth = rangeInput + "%";` . Should't it be `let blueWidth = newVal + "%";` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ah! I missed that.  You're right. It still doesn't resolve the issue as you go further to the left, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the thumb is contained inside the slider's track, a value of 0 doesn't result in the thumb's center being at 0px. The thumb's *left edge* is at 0px. It's *center* is at half the thumb's width.

For the same reason, a value of 100% places the thumb's *right edge* at 100%. Its center is at the end of the track *minus half the thumb's width*.

So you need to account for this when computing the width of your element.

The offset is just the percentage (the slider's value) of the thumb size, normalized to be centered on a slider value of 50. So you get a positive (rightward) offset at 0 and a negative (leftward) offset at 100:

```js
const thumbSize = 37;
const range = document.getElementById("rangeSlider");
const rangeInput = Math.round(range.value);

function updateSlider(value) {
  const blue = document.querySelector(".range__input__right--bg");

  // Account for the thumb size/position:
  // Transition linearly from a positive offset
  // at 0 to a negative offset at 100
  const offset = thumbSize * (0.5 - value / 100);
  
  // use css calc to add the offset to the percentage
  const blueWidth = `calc(${value}% + ${offset}px)`;
  
  blue.style.width = blueWidth;
}


range.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  updateSlider(Number(e.target.value));
});

window.addEventListener('load', updateSlider(range.value));
```

The only other thing I changed was the width of the input, from 105% to 100%:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  ...
```

https://codepen.io/rayhatfield/pen/RwpprzQ

Comment: This makes perfect sense and it's something I didn't account for at all. Of course this would be the solution! Much appreciate @ray-hatfield